# Software not running in wine 1.7 ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wine, 15.04

Kindly assist with an application from Bridgewood Design. i installed a software called cut list plus on wine 15.04. The software installed perfectly, but not showing in my list of program.

When i browse c. Drive, i cant see the Bridgewood design on my programme files but cant run the software.

Please kindly assist

Henry

Answer (score 0):

FAQ : "6.1 How do I run an application once I've installed it?"  at https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.